# fishshell checking equvalancy. (like `==` does in most languages)

Tags: fish

All I want to do is perform a simple equivalency check like you would in other languages with the `==` operator. It would look something like

```
if $var == 0
    echo Hello world!
end
```

I'm a really surprised that the closest thing in the docs I could find is `contains` which allows for this silly makeshift solution

```
if contains $var 0
    echo Hello world!
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `test` builtin, like

```
if test "$var" = 0
    # do stuff
end
```

`test` is also available as `[`, in which case it expects the last argument to be `]`, so you can write

```
if [ "$var" = 0 ]
    # do stuff
end
```

I'm quoting the variable here because `test`s argument parsing (which was taken straight from POSIX) doesn't work well with fish's lists, so if $var doesn't have exactly one element it will break with surprising errors.

Comment: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/commit/50bec2c32ea28b74edee585f4382e6ee7bd93013 adds a few examples and a link to the tutorial.

Comment: Aaand the following commits, since I'm apparently bad at this.